# Isomorphism between trees and forests

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

Let $FF$ be the category of forests, whose objects are strictly partially ordered sets such that for a forest $F$, the set $\{y\in F\mid y<x\}$ is a finite linear order for any $x\in F$, whose cardinality is called the level of $x$, and whose morphisms are the level-preserving and order-preserving functions. The trees form a full subcategory $TT$ of $FF$, where a forest is a tree iff there is exactly one element of level $0$. These are basically acyclic directed graphs (the trees), or disjoint unions of trees (the forests). Now I have proven that by cutting the root of a tree one obtains a functor from TT to FF that is an fully faithful and essentially surjective, and hence defines an equivalence of categories, so these categories are equivalent. But I was wondering: are they also isomorphic? I feel like the answer is no, but I can't prove it. Any thoughts or hints?

For (some of) the comments below: I am not asking whether this functor is an isomorphism, because it clearly isn't, but how to show that there exists no functor that is an isomorphism.

Comment: Can you define an inverse functor?

Comment: A pseudo-inverse is given by "rooting", i.e. adding a point to a forest and connecting all roots to it. This is not an inverse, but that doesn't prove that those categories are not isomorphic, right? Just that this specific functor does not yield an isomorphism.

Comment: Indeed, that is not an inverse. Do you think there is any possible way to know, if I give you the result of cutting of the root of a tree, what that root was? In other words, is the functor given by chopping off the root injective on objects?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but is everybody in the conversation catching that a tree is being assumed to have exactly one root, not just to be a connected forest, as I think is more common? Given that, I'm missing how adjoining a root is not an inverse.

Comment: No, you can't, and no, it isn't. But that only proves that this specific functor is not an isomorphism but only an equivalence, and not that there exists no isomorphism, right?

Comment: Does it help that they are not isomorph for any fixed cardinality of vertices?

Comment: @KevinCarlson The problem is that you are adjoining **a** root, but it's not necessarily the original root... Just goes to show how unnatural (!) isomorphisms of categories feel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one initial object in $FF$, the empty forest $\varnothing$. However, in $TT$, any singleton $\{x\}$ is an initial object. An isomorphism of categories would restrict to a bijection between the set of initial objects in $FF$ and the set of initial objects in $TT$, which doesn't exist.